# Spacing in keyboard row

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-keyboard

How to give spacing in keyboard character a and l ?[image: Preview looks like below image. Kindly help me overcome this problem]

keyboard and txt's bottom are always sticked together as seen on screenshot, I want some space between them, is it possible?

```
   <Row>

        <Key
            android:codes="97"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="a" />
        <Key
            android:codes="115"
            android:keyLabel="s" />
        <Key
            android:codes="100"
            android:keyLabel="d" />
        <Key
            android:codes="102"
            android:keyLabel="f" />
        <Key
            android:codes="103"
            android:keyLabel="g" />
        <Key
            android:codes="104"
            android:keyLabel="h" />
        <Key
            android:codes="106"
            android:keyLabel="j" />
        <Key
            android:codes="107"
            android:keyLabel="k" />
        <Key
            android:codes="108"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="l" />


    </Row>
```

Comment: Didn't understand, what is sticked to what ?

Comment: need to add left margin and right margin in keyboard button which is only A & L.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="97"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:horizontalGap="9.5%"    //Note this
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="a"/>
    <Key
        android:codes="115"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyLabel="s" />
    <Key
        android:codes="100"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyLabel="d" />
    <Key
        android:codes="102"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyLabel="f" />
    <Key
        android:codes="103"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyLabel="g" />
    <Key
        android:codes="104"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyLabel="h" />
    <Key
        android:codes="106"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyLabel="j" />
    <Key
        android:codes="107"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyLabel="k" />
    <Key
        android:codes="108"
        android:keyLabel="l"
        android:keyWidth="9%p"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

By setting [`android:keyWidth`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:keyWidth) to 9% for 9 keys you'll have a sum of 81%.
Then use [`android:horizontalGap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:horizontalGap) at the first `Key` to add a *margin*. Finally you'll have an *empty space* to the end which has the remaining space size.

**Note**: I set `horizontalGap` to 9.5% to have an equal size at the beginning and the end of the row.